# Get started with jogl ,DebugGL class can't found

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

Good day, everyone!
I'd start learning openGL and JOGL library, download last version jogl, from off site, import to classpath of my project jogl-all.jar and gluegen.jar (using IDEA), and these imported successful, but i can't find DebugGL class, this very important for me, cos' i learning by [this](http://www.land-of-kain.de/docs/jogl/) tutorial, so what i do wrong?
P.s. sorry for my English, and stupid question, but i try google it, and get poor information.

UPD: I find in all jogl package only DebugGL4, but GL don't have method 
glShadeModel and no const GL_SMOOTH and GLCapabilities don't have empty constructor. [Listing](http://www.land-of-kain.de/docs/jogl/MyJoglCanvasStep1.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you've pointed to is way out of date.  The version of JOGL that exposes it's functionality as javax.media.opengl isn't full featured.  If you want to use JOGL you should be using the jars and tutorials available at http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/